# Can a VPN to a personal computer be monitored? 

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I work from home and use a work laptop with VPN connection.  If I have a personal computer hooked up to the same wireless connection as my work computer (not on VPN though), can they monitor what I am doing on my personal computer?

Answer (score 0):

No, other computers on your LAN are not visible in any way to your employer. Additionally, they may not even monitor your work laptop's internet browsing if they use split tunneling on the VPN.

Comment: Everywhere I've ever worked, the still ran web browsing from my work laptop through the VPN to their proxy/firewall then out.  Companies are getting very protective of what you do on their computers.

Comment: It depends on how much overhead they want to impart on their VPN concentrator, or if they feel the need to filter everything you do on company equipment. Sometimes its a compromise.