# Can employer track IP usage on home computers through VPN?

Tags: vpn

My work PC computer(in my home office) is connected to my home router via ethernet cable and I'm connected to my company server through VPN (NetExtender). If I'm logged onto the remote terminal server on my work PC and I have my personal macbook connected wirelessly through the same router, can they track my internet usage on my personal macbook because they are using the same router?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VPN Privacy Question](http://superuser.com/questions/276588/vpn-privacy-question)

Comment: Can they? Yes.
Will they? Probably not, unless you are hacking their system and stealing trade secrets.
What can they do with the information? Not much without a warrant. Which again won't be an issue unless you are causing problems.

Comment: @TheX Explain what (which IPs...internal or external), and how they are going to track his home systems please.

Comment: all they have to do is run a backtrace on anything connecting to their network with will give them an external IP, once they secure a warrant they can get the identifying information from the ISP.

Comment: @TheX: your answer is unrelated to VPN or not, "find out the external ip, get a warrant and ask isp" is the general solution to "how to sniff the network of xyz". OP wants to know if the employer can install something on the work machine to sniff the home network.

Comment: Technically I didn't answer his question, I only commented...

Answer (score 1):

They generally won't be able to track your non-routable internal addresses(often 192.168.x.x), but of course, they can track your routable external IP address (the one your ISP gives you). The IP on you macbook should be safe since it is not connecting to their VPN, and getting an internal IP address from them.

Even as in that comment to the question that Moab posted, if they did force Internet browsing or other services through their VPN, the IP address the VPN would give you on their network would be recorded, and even that is not the case with you RDP'ing since all the work would be done on the Terminal Server.